# Why modules link is not coming on Administrator Main page?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, module, drupal-modules

I have added two modules in my drupal site called....
1. me alias 
2. Mime mail

Whenever we add new modules to our site,
it has links on admin page.

but after activating modules, i can't see the links on admin page.

but this happens only on server but on my localhost i can see the modules links on admin page.

i have put screenshot of the problem, in image you can see that, i have activated both modules but on admin page....i can't see its links.
why is not activated.

i have tried to clear all the cache and then try again but its not coming then also.

Here is the screen shot
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Did you remember to give required permissions?

Comment: yes...i have checked..... i gave them both full permission...then also.... i don't get that links...but i get both modules links are coming on my localhost without changing any permission....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes i found the problem...... i was always getting one error....about semaphore table not exists.

so thats why whenever i include any new module then its links not coming on the side.

but now is coming....bcz i had manually include table on server.

thank u both for ur replay....

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this behavior before but haven't looked into it too much.
Try to disable the modules causing issues. Then enable them. Clear the cache and run update.

Comment: yes..exactly i had done...but then also i don't know why it still not working..so tomorrow i am trying to update whole drupal. lets see what happen then....